# Filter in vba for excel multidimensional array

Tags: vba, excel, multidimensional-array

I need to fetch the number and details of data like a multidimensional array. The probleme is I need to make it with VBA so it's only with 1 click.

I need to fetch the data according to the date, every tuesday I have to fetch the data according to the new excel.

From that file I need to:

1. Remove blank date ( column D, E, F)
2. Count the number of row between the oldest date to the current tuesday minus 9 days
3. Count the number of rows between the current tuesday minus 8 days and current tuesday minus 3 days
4. Regroup some data together
5. On click, display the details

To illustrate that, I need to filter an array like that

```
ColA         ColB        ColC    ColD   ColE    ColF     ColG       Details
PIM12          I          00                    Asia
PIM12          I          00                    Asia
PIM12          I          03      03      03      15      MAT        Asia
PIM12          I          01      11      03      15      DAP        Asia
PIM12          I          01      24      02      15      APM        Asia
PIM12          I          00                                         Europe
PIM12          I          00                                         Europe
PIM12          I          01      24      02      15      MAT        USA
PIM12          I          00                                         USA
PIM12          I          02      17      02      15      JOU        USA
PIM12          I          03      05      03      15      APM        Australia
PIM12          I          00                                         Australia
PIMDE          I          00                                         Australia
PIMDE          I          00                                         Australia
PIMDE          I          21      24      02      15      JOU        
PIMDE          I          21      24      02      15      JOU        
PIMDE          I          07      03      03      15      JOU        
PIMDE          I          21      24      02      15      JOU    
..........
```

To get a multidimentional array like so:

```
Centre  FROM X TO DAY - 9   FROM DAY -8 TO DAY - 3
DECINES       3                     2
    Asia      1                     1
    Europe    2                     1
OULLINS       3                     0
    Africa    3                     0
RILLIEUX      3                     4
    Asia      1                     2
    Australia 1                     1
    USA       1                     1
VENISSIEUX    6                     5
    Asia      1                     1
    Australia 1                     3
    Europe    2                     1
    USA       2                     0
Total         15                    22
```

which from x to day - 8 represents all the data from the first date found in the filter to the date of today ( assuming we are tuesday ) minus 8 days. And same on the from day minus 3.

Another illustration could be that:

```
from x         day -9        day -3
======data========>
                  ======data=====>
```

---

I started this code but I'm wrong with it, I need to regroup these:

- "PIM12", "PTL12", "PIC12" and rename it to RILLIEUX
- "PIM52", "PTL52", "PIC52" renamed to OULLINS
- "PIMSE", "PTL31", "PIC31" renamed to VENISSIEUX
- "PIMDE", "PTLDE", "PICDE" renamed to DECINES

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub VerifLignesAvecAutoFilter()

Dim DataBlock As Range, Dest As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim FeuilOne, FeuilTwo, FeuilThree As Worksheet
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim i, c, idx As Integer
Dim madate, xlDate As Date
Dim xlDay, xlMonth, xlYear As String
Dim realDay, realMonth, realYear As String
Dim dataRillieux, dataOullins, dataVenissieux, dataDecines As Integer
Dim dataRillieuxX, dataOullinsX, dataVenissieuxX, dataDecinesX As Integer


'variable qui referencent les trois feuilles dont nous avons besoin
Set FeuilOne = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
Set FeuilTwo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2")
Set FeuilThree = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil3")


finalRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil2").Range("A1").End(xlUp).row

idx = 0
dataRillieux = 0
dataRillieuxX = 0
dataOullins = 0
dataOullinsX = 0
dataVenissieux = 0
dataVenissieuxX = 0
dataDecines = 0
dataDecinesX = 0

madate = CDate("24/02/2015")

realDay = Format(Date, "dd")
realMonth = Format(Date, "mm")
realYear = Format(Date, "yy")

realMonth = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mm")

With FeuilTwo.Cells.ClearContents
End With

With FeuilThree.Cells.ClearContents
End With

Set Dest = FeuilTwo.Cells(1, 1) '<~ c'est dans cette feuille que nous mettons les données

'identification du block de données dans lequel nous appliquerons le autofilter
With FeuilOne
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    Set DataBlock = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

'application des autofilter à la column D,E,F
With DataBlock
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("*PIM*", "*PIC*", "*PTL*") 'column A
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="=" & realYear 'column F represent year
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<=*" & realMonth 'column E represent month
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & madate
    'on copie ce qui a été filtré dans le Dest
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dest
End With




For Each c In FeuilTwo.Range("A:A")
    Select Case c

        '********** RILLIEUX **********
        Case "PIM12", "PTL12", "PIC12"
        xlDay = FeuilTwo.Cells(idx, "F").Value
        xlMonth = FeuilTwo.Cells(idx, "E").Value
        xlYear = FeuilTwo.Cells(idx, "D").Value

        xlDate = CDate(xlDay + "/" + xlMonth + "/" + xlYear)

        If xlDate > madate - 3 Then
            GoTo continuer
        ElseIf xlDate >= madate - 8 And xlDate <= madate - 3 Then
         dataRillieuxX = dataRillieux + 1
        End If

        FeuilThree.Range("C2") = dataRillieux
        FeuilThree.Range("B2") = dataRillieuxX

        '********** OULLINS **********
        Case "PIM52", "PTL52", "PIC52"

        '********** VENISSIEUX **********
        Case "PIMSE", "PTL31", "PIC31"

        '********** DECINES **********
        Case "PIMDE", "PTLDE", "PICDE"

    End Select
continuer:
    idx = idx + 1
Next c


'on enleve l'autofilter
With FeuilOne
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then .ShowAllData
End With

End Sub
```

If any VBA Guru out there could help I would be appreciated.

Comment: I've having a hard time reconciling the sample data with the expected results. e.g. *PIMDE* either has a region (*Australia*) and no dates or dates and no region. From your description it shouldn't show up in the report at all. The sample data provided should be able to produce the expected results or we are just guessing.

Comment: hello Jeeped, thank you for your help.
you're true Jeeped, i've reworked the data a bit to be more explicit but in fact i've complicated things

like the e.g PIMDE, if at least i have a date and no region ( australia ) i need to fetch it ( count it ).

the region is an extra, if there is region it's OK we count it, if no then we grab the data for PIMDE that fit either in the x to day -9 or day - 9 to day -3

Comment: any help plz VBA Gurus ? :)

Comment: could use any help around vba gurus plz